# Cakephp Routes And General Routing

Tags: url, cakephp, routes

I have a controller with an action and a variable like this:

```
 class AccountsController extends AppController
 {
      function profile($username = null)
     {
     }
 }
```

The url for this page is:

```
 [domain]/accounts/profile/[username]
```

How do I make it:

```
 [domain]/[username]
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
//in your routes.php file
Router::connect('/:username',
array('controller' => 'accounts', 'action' => 'profile'),
  array(
      'pass' => array('username')
  )
);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: that works, having some trouble with the error routing now, page goes white when a username is not found

Comment: you could have some check in your controllers profile function to display appropriate page or message when username is empty..

Comment: i have this in when the username can't be found: but the page goes white -  $this->cakeError('error404');