# Individual Profile / User Page in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, social-networking

I am in the process of building a webapp in cakePHP where once a user has signed up they would have their own profile page that can be seen by other members. Ideally I would like a nice url e.g. www.website.com/davejones but I can settle for something that was like www.website.com/uid=235325.

What would be the best way of going about this?

Comment: similar to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753671/cakephp-routes-and-general-routing

Comment: Thanks. That answers the renaming url part. I am stuggling with how you would create a separate page for each user at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you would just add a `profile` method to your `UsersController` that takes the user id/username as a parameter and then just serve that page.

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function profile($uid) {
        $data = $this->User->findById($uid);
        $this->set(compact('data'));
    }

}
```

Would make all data of that user (incl. associated data, if your models setup properly) go into the $data variable that you can call from your view. Do with it what you want there.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and I receive an error saying: Warning (512): DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check.  Node references:
Aro: Array. I have followed the ACL tutorial from the cake website to get to this stage.

Comment: That message just tells you that you're trying to access an ACO that is not in your database yet (or your ARO is not linked to it). For the above example, you probably have not added the Users/Profile ACO yet.